# Failure in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container.ReadItemAsync() - json parsing - unexpected character

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am porting some C# code from Microsoft.Azure.Documents to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos. I created a small test case to try to get it working just accessing CosmosDB before testing it with my full application. I'll add my full code further below, but here is what I believe is the relevant content.

```
try {
   Container container = client.GetContainer(DocumentDBDatabaseName, collectionId);
   RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
   ThroughputProperties tputprops = await container.ReadThroughputAsync(requestOptions);
   Console.WriteLine($"Throughput: {tputprops.Throughput}");
   ContainerProperties containerProperties = await container.ReadContainerAsync();
   Console.WriteLine($"Container props: {containerProperties}");
   // We don't use any partition keys, so use PartitionKey.None
   ItemRequestOptions iro = new ItemRequestOptions();
   ItemResponse<string> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<string>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);
   return result;  // successful return
} catch (CosmosException exc) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}", exc.StatusCode, exc);
} catch (Exception exc) {
   Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", exc);
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
Throughput: 400
Container props: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerProperties
Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosSerializerCore.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ToObjectpublic[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.b__8_0[T](ResponseMessage cosmosResponseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ProcessMessage[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage, Func`2 createResponse)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateItemResponse[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.d__56`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.d__38`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestCosmos_ns.TestCosmos_cl.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\buchs\Work-NCS\TestCosmos2\TestCosmos\Program.cs:line 46
```

The documentDBstorageid is simply a string which matches the document ID found in the database. The database does not use partition keys. Obviously the container is fine as I can gather other data from it without exception.

Here is the fuller code

```
// Package: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos --version 3.12.0
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

namespace TestCosmos_ns
{
    class TestCosmos_cl
    {
        private static string DocumentDBDatabaseName = "mydbname";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task Ta = AsyncMain(args);
            Ta.Wait();  // Wait for all async tasks to close.
        }

        public static async Task AsyncMain(string[] args)
        {
            // corresponds to CosmosDB container
            string EmployeeCollection = "directory";
            string docId2 = GetDocumentDBStorageId("company", "companyid", "locationx");
            string u = await GetDocumentById(EmployeeCollection, docId2);
            Console.WriteLine("GetDocumentById returns:");
            Console.WriteLine(u);
            bool v = DocumentExists(EmployeeCollection, docId2);
            Console.WriteLine("DocumentExists() returns:");
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
        public static async Task<string> GetDocumentById(string collectionId, string documentDBStorageId)
        {
            CosmosClient client = GetDocumentDBClient();
            try {
                Container container = client.GetContainer(DocumentDBDatabaseName, collectionId);
                RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                ThroughputProperties tputprops = await container.ReadThroughputAsync(requestOptions);
                Console.WriteLine($"Throughput: {tputprops.Throughput}");
                ContainerProperties containerProperties = await container.ReadContainerAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Container props: {containerProperties}");
                // We don't use any partition keys, so use PartitionKey.None
                ItemRequestOptions iro = new ItemRequestOptions();
                ItemResponse<string> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<string>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);
                return result;  // successful return
            } catch (CosmosException exc) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}", exc.StatusCode, exc);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", exc);
            }
            return "";  // return in exception situations
        }

        public static bool DocumentExists(string collectionId, string documentDBStorageId)
        {
            // OK, totally cheating. Just try to retrieve the document, if we get back blank, then there
            // was an exception and it doesn't exist.
            Task<string> getResult = GetDocumentById(collectionId, documentDBStorageId);
            getResult.Wait();
            string result = getResult.Result;
            if (result.Length == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private static CosmosClient TheCosmosClient = null;
        public static CosmosClient GetDocumentDBClient()
        {
            string DocumentDBEndpointUrl = "https://mydb.documents.azure.com:443/";
            string DocumentDBPrimaryKey = "myprimarykey...==";
            TheCosmosClient = TheCosmosClient ?? new CosmosClient(DocumentDBEndpointUrl, DocumentDBPrimaryKey);
            return TheCosmosClient;
        }

        private static string NormalizePath(string result)
        {
            string toReplace = " ,.<>?;:'\"`~!@#$%^&*()-=+";

            foreach (char c in toReplace)
                result = result.Replace(c, '_');

            result = result.Replace("__", "_");
            return result;
        }
        public static string GetDocumentDBStorageId(string companyName, string companyId, string locationName) => NormalizePath($"Employees_{companyName}_{companyId}_{locationName}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

use this code:

```
ItemResponse<JObject> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);
```

instead of:

```
ItemResponse<string> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<string>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);
```

Comment: Hi Steve. This did the trick! Then using result.Resource.ToString() to get the string value of the JSON.

Too bad the documentation didn't help with this. I added a comment to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.cosmos.cosmoscontainer.readitemasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Azure_Cosmos_CosmosContainer_ReadItemAsync__1_System_String_Azure_Cosmos_PartitionKey_Azure_Cosmos_ItemRequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: Just to explain the actions taken:<br/>
1) add project reference to Newtonsoft.Json - updated to latest<br/>
2) added:  `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`<br/>
3) changed the request code to:<br/>
`ItemResponse<JObject> result = await container.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(documentDBStorageId, PartitionKey.None, iro);` <br/>
`return result.Resource.ToString();  // successful return`

Comment: I'd love an explanation of why this change helps if anyone can spare the time.  I'm dealing with the same error message from the Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are passing multiple values for id `("company", "companyid", "locationx")`

You can only pass a single value for id for ReadItemAsync(). If you want to pass multiple values you can use a query with an IN() clause.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. Those three strings a combined into a single string to form the proper ID. See the very last method.